# Fetch single element from json_decode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this code:

```
<?php
    $fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
    $fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
    $fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = 'http://apple.com'";

    $apifql = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
    $json = file_get_contents($apifql);
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    print_r($obj);
?>
```

that outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [url] => http://apple.com [normalized_url] => http://www.apple.com/ [share_count] => 366493 [like_count] => 514795 [comment_count] => 298452 [total_count] => 1179740 [commentsbox_count] => 0 [comments_fbid] => 381975869314 [click_count] => 16558 ) )
```

How can I define into a string only the `commentsbox_count`? I need it for my database.

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you posted the raw JSON instead of the `print_r` output. Reading JSON is nicer, and you can paste it into something such as jsonlint to format it nicely and quickly see the structure.

Comment: Didn't get your question. What is it that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it through `$obj[0]->commentsbox_count`.

The top-level element is a one-element array with the only key being `0`. This element is a stdClass object (which is pretty much like an array but with properties instead of array elements) so you access the element using `->name`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your fast answer !

Comment: No problem, please don't forget to +1 and accept the answer in a few minutes - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/147015 for details on who/how to accept answers.